# What type of adjective is "funky"?

Tags: adjectives, parts-of-speech

"Funky" is an adjective but it is it a particular type of adjective?  It's certainly not comparative or demonstrative.  I have looked it up but all I can find is that it is an adjective.

Comment: The "comparative adjectives" would be ***funkier*** and ***funkiest***. English has very few "demonstrative adjectives" (***This** sentence starts with a demonstrative adjective, whereas ***this*** is more properly a demonstrative *pronoun*). Most adjectives are just "adjectives".

Comment: What kind of adjective is *red, bumpy, tall* etc?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'd go so far as to say that English has **no** demonstrative adjectives. _This_ sentence starts with a demonstrative determiner.

Comment: @Janus: Yes, if you're prepared to divide English words into a larger number of categories. But just working from the basic definition [the function of an adjective is to modify a noun or pronoun](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22the+function+of+an+adjective+is+to+modify+a+noun+or+pronoun%22&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB712GB712&oq=%22the+function+of+an+adjective+is+to+modify+a+noun+or+pronoun%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i61.76374349j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), it's not unreasonable to lump determiners in with adjectives (where ***adverb** = pretty much every other small & "awkward" category*).

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how it is used, it is either an **attributive** or a **predicative** adjective.

It is an attributive adjective if it is used as: a funky X.

It is a predicative adjective if it is used as: X is funky.

Further reading: [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/attributive-and-predicative-adjectives) on attributive and predicative adjectives.

Comment: Attributive and predicative are not really _types_ of adjective, but _uses_ of them. Similarly, in “Susan saw the dog”, _Susan_ and _the dog_ are used as subject and object, respectively; but they are not ‘subject nouns’ or ‘object nouns’.

Comment: _Funky in his retro smoking-jacket, Aloysius leaned on the bar_ is an _absolute_ usage.